# javascript - square bracket before method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone tell me what the square bracket before the method call means? I've never seen it before...

`return [].concat(privateUserList);`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` creates an empty array. `[].concat` is a method on the array, which that code is passing `privateUserList` into. The end result is a new array containing the same entries as `privateUserList` (if it's an array) or containing `privateUserList` itself (if it's not an array).

It's theoretically inefficient, because it creates and throws away an array (since `concat` creates a *new* array, the one created by `[]` is thrown away). But this an other common related idioms that create and throw away arrays are quite common and probably get optimized out.

If (again) we assume `privateUserList` is an array, the more direct way to do that is:

```
return privateUserList.slice();
```

If we wanted to support anything *array-like* (`concat` doesn't), we'd use:

```
return Array.prototype.slice.call(privateUserList);
```

or on ES2015 (or with a shim):

```
return Array.from(privateUserList);
```

Answer (score 2):

`[]` is an empty array. Just like `[1,2,3,4]` would be an array with four elements.

That snippet creates an empty array and then concatenates to it `privateUserList`.